# jQuery On() is not working for $(document)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, backbone.js, backbone-events

I am currently in the process of integrating the dropkick.js plugin into my app, but I have run into a few snags.  When I change backbone views the events do not work properly and the `.live()` event associated in dropkick.js just flat out doesn't work at all.  Nothing fires.  I decided to upgrade this to using the `.on()` function and got it sort of working (even though it still deletes my url for some reason).

This doesn't work at all:

```
$(document).on("click", ".dk_toggle", function() {
```

This only works somewhat:

```
$(".content").on("click", ".dk_toggle", function() {
```

Do you know why `document` doesn't work at all?

My backbone `$el` is `$(".content")`.

Comment: have you checked the firebug console for errors?

Comment: the version of jQuery library you are using is??

Comment: Yes, no errors are reported. The issue is that by default dropkick.js uses the live function which works fine when loading the view that requires the drop down on a hard page refresh, but the menu click event won't fire when I transition from another view to the view with the menu. This is the reason I wanted to modify it using the on function. I thought maybe it was because live was deprecated.  Ironically... if I just use a regular click event... wrap it in a setTimeout function and make sure that the menu is visable before the click event happens then the event works.

Comment: try using jQuery(whatever) instead of $(whatever) . sometimes it makes a difference

Comment: @Youn Elan - I tried.  No difference.  I don't even care the document isn't working.  The thing that really bothers me is the $(".content") doesn't work fully.  When I go to navigate to my second backbone view and click the menu the menu loads fine, but my URL goes to the root and I don't see this anywhere in the code. I think this is happening do to some weird event binding. I also have e.preventDefault() and return false at the bottom of my click event.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of document, use `body`. It basically gives the same behavior.

```
$('body').on("click", ".dk_toggle", function() {
//....
});
```

Comment: I tried that actually. Body wasn't working for me either.  The only thing that sort of worked was .content

Comment: @JasonBiondo, That's a bit hard to believe. Can you show me this case?

Answer (score 0):

The first example demonstrates event delegation.

The second example binds the event handler directly to the element. The event will still bubble (unless you prevent that in the handler) but since the handler is bound to the target, you won't see the effects of this process.

[**Test Run**](http://jsperf.com/jquery-on-document-vs-id-selector#)

Comment: Can you explain to me how to prevent the bubbling of the event when it is bound to the handler?

Comment: @JasonBiondo using stopPropagation.

Comment: The URL still goes to root after navigating from the first view